# Problem with JGit at Bamboo elastic-agents

Tags: amazon-ec2, bamboo, jgit

I have some problems with git at Bamboo elastic-agents. Cloning repo is ok, but when it push changes to server build falls with error:

```
An error 'ssh://git@our_server_url:7999: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$YesNoType:The authenticity of host 'our_server_url' can't be established.RSA key fingerprint is 04:a0:ab:f6:39:92:1f:21:9d:0c:f4:3e:f2:5e:99:4e.Are you sure you want to continue connecting?' occurred while pushing branch: branch_name to url: ssh://git@our_server_url:7999/repo_name.git
```

This problem occurs at elastic-agents only. All keys are equal in AWS and remote agents.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to turn 'SSL verification' off? Did you try to configure `http.sslVerify` to `false`?

Comment: SSL verification disabled, and if I push changes from AWS instance from shell, it works correctly. Problem occurs only in bamboo builds with jgit.